# Access Data from a Json Object with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, json

I have some JSON shown in the image below. There is an object called `0` under items.

I want to get the attributes inside items. How can I access it with jQuery or Javascript?

[image]

This is what I have so far:

```
 jQuery.getJSON('http://localhost/magento/js/primitives/js/SpaceTreeRegion.json',
     function(jsonData) {
     jQuery.each(jsonData, function(currentRegionNode, jsonData) {
         alert(jsonData.items.product_name);
     });
});
```

This code gives an error: `jsonData.items.value is undefined`

The JSON is like this:

```
  [
      {
          "category_id": "Clothes",
          "Items": [
              {
                  "product_id": 1,
                  "price": 50,
                  "product_name": "Shirts"
              },
              {
                  "product_id": 2,
                  "price": 60,
                 "product_name": "T-Shirt"
              }
          ]
     }
 ]
```

I want access to `product_id`,`price` and `product_name` for each `items` in an Object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this code

```
  jQuery.getJSON('your json url', function(yourJsonData) {
     jQuery.each(yourJsonData[0].Items, function(key, customData) {
            alert(customData.product_name);
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

This code should give you the idea:

Example:
`alert(jsonData[0].Items[0].product_id);`

Try this $.each then:

```
`$.each(jsonData[0].Items, function (i, item) {
            alert(item.product_id);
            alert(item.price);
            alert(item.product_name);
        });`
```

Comment: this is giving only one result...and i don't want use for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try this json file:

```
 {
      "category_id": "Clothes",
      "Items": [
          {
              "product_id": 1,
              "price": 50,
              "product_name": "Shirts"
          },
          {
              "product_id": 2,
              "price": 60,
             "product_name": "T-Shirt"
          }
      ]
 }
```

Then parse it like this:

```
$.each(jsonData.Items, function(index, value){
  alert(value.product_name)
});
```

Comment: what you trying to say?

Comment: There was additional [] outside of the data, what results in an extra array in the parsed data.

Comment: Yes, but you are doing the same mistake later in the code. There is no jsonData.items.value. You also don't need to go use  jQuery.each(jsonData, function(currentRegionNode, jsonData). You have jsonData.Items[0].product_name and others. jsonData represents all the data from the json, then there is an Items array which holds objects.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because Items hasnt value.

```
for(var i=0; i<jsonData.items.length; i++){
    var youritem = jsonData.items[i]; /*this is your item*/
    console.log(jsonData.items[i].product_name);/*one of your product names*/
}
```

here is your code:

```
 jQuery.getJSON('http://localhost/magento/js/primitives/js/SpaceTreeRegion.json',
       function(jsonData) {
 jQuery.each(jsonData, function(currentRegionNode, jsonData) {

                   alert(this.items);/*this is an object also*/
                   alert(this.items[0].product_name)/*this is your child arrays property*/
                   alert(this.items[1].product_name)/*this is second one*/

});
```

});

so you can loop in `this.items` again

Comment: this is taking to much time....so i want to do it with out for loop....batter i can you jQuery

Comment: ok your main idea is loop in json with each. but you have two arrays. and you loop parent one. do same thing for child array.

Comment: yes right..but when i access to child node it's giving error "jsonData.items is undefine"

Comment: your oloping in categories you should also loop items for each categories.

Comment: this.Items[0].product_name

Comment: your trying to get your main arrays property use "this" statement

Comment: i also tried with jsonData.items with .each then it gives error "obj is undefine

Answer (score 0):

Change your `each` loop to something like this -

```
jQuery.each(jsonData['Items'], function(currentRegionNode, jsonItemData) {
    alert(jsonItemData.product_name); // will output 'Shirts ', 'T-Shirt'
});
```